# What's the appeal process for a user who got falsely banned for GPT-generated content?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

So, Stack Overflow doesn't disclose the process of identifying GPT-generated content to avoid gaming. But, what's the appeal process if your account gets banned for 30 days for posting GPT-generated content falsely? Must the victim wait for 30 days?

There is no appeal process for answer bans per official docs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans.

Comment: question and answer quality-based bans are different from what is being given out in this case.

Comment: There's always the [Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) option. Where you can explicitly select *I want to appeal a suspension*.

Comment: People who get suspended also have an appeal opportunity by replying to the mod message

Comment: Too bad no one wrote them as actual answers...

Comment: I can't believe we have no canonical for "how to appeal a suspension"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: @Dharman ... well, that's just sad

Comment: open notepad, write appeal, save it with a descriptive name, then drop it in the recycle bin and wait out the suspension

Comment: But... but... but... you can't get the fancy formatting in notepad! How are you going to impress the recycle bin with your leet artistic skillz if you use notepad?

Comment: Fine, you can use microsoft word

Comment: @user4581301 You obviously use the notepad to write an assembly program that outputs an entire hour-long video containing a complaint, duh :p

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine at least it's not brainf*ck code.

Answer (score 11):

This is something that is best to be dealt with when it comes up.  Today, there's no real process that rectifies "false" bans from rate limiting or anything like that, and it isn't likely that the moderators are going to go on a ban-happy spree dealing with this.